# How to revert GDM to default Ubuntu 18.10 (to utilize new lock/login screens)

Tags: gnome, login-screen, lock-screen, gdm, 18.10

My question is pretty much summed up by the title. GNOME 3.30 touts a new lock/login screen, yet Ubuntu 18.10 lacks any changes to GDM. I was just wondering if there was a way to actually SEE and USE these changes in Cosmic. Thanks in advance.
THIS

[image]

Doesn't match this: [image]

Though I may have gotten the "mock-up" and the real login screen release
 confused???

Comment: Is your 18.10 an upgrade, or a fresh install? First, at the login screen, select/enter your username, then click the cog wheel icon, then select `Ubuntu`, then enter your password. Log out, and you should see the GNOME/gdm3 login screen. If that's not it, we'll try something else. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: It's an upgrade. Thanks, will report back. Personal note: heynnema, you're awesome, always answering questions on here.

Comment: Didn't work.... "ubuntu" has BEEN my session, since forever.. (18.04)
The login screen is exactly the same as in 18.04.
Keep in mind I used sudo apt-get do-release upgrade for it, the GUI utility wasn't working :(

Comment: Then lets make sure that gdm3 is set as your default DE. In `terminal`, type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`. Note which shows as default, and select gdm3 as default, click OK. Then reboot. Report back... make sure to use @heynnema or I may miss your replies. And thanks for the nice comment :-)

Comment: edited... may explain why I think it's different.... ofc@ comment you've answered a lot of my questions now....

Comment: The second image isn't from Ubuntu. Where did you get it? What are the 4 arrows in the top left of the images? Are you running in a VM?

Comment: How did solsTiCe get an accept, when I've been helping you for the last hour? My previous comment indicated that your second image was not from Ubuntu.

Comment: omgubuntu...... the arrows are to expand the picture. it's a screenshot of an image, that has arrows on the edge of it to expand the image.

Comment: @heynnema you helped but did not provide an answer. I provided one before you copy mine. I don't see why I did not deserve the 'Accepted answer'.

Comment: @RobertSederholm Please give me that 'accept'. Thanks :-)

Comment: I already made my choice, the person that helped me first, and put more of the effort in got the point(s). You just pointed out the obvious, WHEN it was obvious. If you have any further problems with this. contacts (a) moderator(s). Thank you, have a good day.

Comment: @solsTiCe I had been helping the OP for the **prior hour**, and my last comment, just before you came on board, was that the second image (which he had just posted) wasn't from Ubuntu, and where/how did he get it. There wasn't enough time yet to finalize a complete answer, when you posted yours. This is not a competition, but what's fair is fair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments...

After looking at the two images you edited into your question, it became more obvious what you were trying to describe.

Image #1 is from 18.10, and you can tell it's different from 18.04 because of the green Sign In button.

Image #2 is not from any standard Ubuntu installation currently offered.

Answer (score 4):

Your *Zamifra Honcescu* is a **mock-up login/lock screen** ([design mock-up here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/LockUnlockLogin)) targeted at gnome 3.30 that never made it into the *final release*. Hence the gnome 3.30 login screen still look quite the same that before and than the current ubuntu version.

May be that new design will be part of gnome 3.32 ? One never knows. And may be Ubuntu 19.04 ?