# Change Gnome lock screen on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes

this thing is really getting on my nerves so here's the problem.

[I'm using this guy's theme on my Ubuntu 18.04](https://github.com/vinceliuice/vimix-gtk-themes)  and his version has a very nice Login Screen, but when I lock my computer I get that basic Ubuntu login screen.

Is there any way to get the Login Screen style on the lock screen as well?

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided, there is no screenshot for the Login Screen, can you attach that pic?

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/a/1089956/739431

Comment: Here you go @PRATAP , sorry for the quality but I couldn't take with printscreen :v ; https://imgur.com/a/7oQNIO1

Comment: i guess you are looking for that color change only rite?

Comment: nope i'm looking for the whole style beacuse it's different from the ubuntu's one, if i wanted to change the color i wouldn't be asking

Comment: i had the same problem while trying to install LightDM and ditch Gnome's screen, but LightDM worked only when i was logging out not when i was locking my pc

Comment: oh, sorry you attached your log in screen image. i have requested for the one you are looking about.. from the link i did not find the log in screen pic.

Comment: nah, I just want to know if it's possible (it should be though) to replace Ubuntu's lock screen with that custom login screen

Comment: i am sorry again, can you attach that "custom login screen" ? where is it? i did not see.

Comment: it's the imgur link https://imgur.com/a/7oQNIO1

Comment: Ok, the link you attached imgur.com/a/7oQNIO1 is from which theme?

Comment: The attached imgur link it's from the github theme (Vimix), that is the screen I get when i restart my computer or log out, I want the same theme whenever I lock my screen too beacuse I really don't like that Ubuntu default gnome screen, you get me

Comment: Ok, i got the clarity now. let me go through it. sorry for asking you many questions above. now i understood.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1091507/739431